# Keep getting 550 SSL/TLS required on the control channel with PHP and Python

Tags: php, python, ftp

```
import urllib.request

urllib.request.urlretrieve('ftp://abcxyz@abcxyz/foo', '20170622111600.csv')
```

I get a error of `urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error ftp error: error_perm('550 SSL/TLS required on the control channel',)>`. I also get this error with PHP (different script), which I assumed was a bug (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=36103).

I'm able to login via Filezilla without any issues though.

What could be the problem? Maybe the `.` at the end of my password? Do I need to possibly escape this somehow?

Comment: Tried with `ftps://abc..` ?

Comment: With the python script `    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: ftps>`

Comment: The built-in `ftplib` module can help here.

Comment: Also show us your PHP code.